# How to wait for the event inside a function?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to write a function in VB.Net WPF application for retrieving document’s height in MS WebBrowser control. I can get this value only after some time, when page has been rendered. So, I tried:

```
Private Function GetHeight(ByVal htmlstring As String) As Integer
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser 'Declare WebBrowser
    wb.Width = 940 'set Width
    wb.NavigateToString(htmlstring) 'Navigate to content
    Do Until wb.IsLoaded 'Wait until page is rendered

    Loop
    'Get DOM Document
    Dim doc As mshtml.HTMLDocument = wb.Document
    'Get sought value
    Dim RetVal As Integer = CInt(doc.body.getAttribute("scrollHeight").ToString)
    doc = Nothing : wb.Dispose() : wb = Nothing 'Free variables
    Return RetVal 'Return value
End Function
```

But calling such function causes application to freeze. What should I do? Do I need to implement Async and Await keywords, as well as Threading.Tasks and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, IsLoaded is a framework element property that indicates whether or not the control has been loaded for presentation, *not* whether the WebBrowser control's web page has been loaded.

While I question why you would instantiate a browser and have it navigate to a page in a method called "GetHeight"... what I think you want to do here is subscribe to the LoadCompleted event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Perhaps you can construct your webbrowser and have it navigate in a different method, and subscribe to the LoadCompleted event with your GetHeight method?

*Edit* I neglected to mention that because you declared your browser control outside of xaml, the control will never be loaded (and thus, navgiation won't work) because it's not in the visual tree of the WPF application. You'll have to either use a webbrowser already declared in xaml (which I would recommend), or add it programmatically with something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel x:Name="MainPanel">
    <Button Click="Button_Click"> Clicky</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Class MainWindow

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser 'Declare WebBrowser
    wb.Width = 940 'set Width
    Me.MainPanel.Children.Add(wb)
    wb.NavigateToString("www.stackoverflow.com")

    AddHandler wb.LoadCompleted, Sub(s, ee) DoSomething()
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
    MessageBox.Show("blah")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped. Indeed, I must add WebBrowser to Visual Tree; otherwise it will not navigate.
By the way, I've solved my another problem by inserting Forms.Application.DoEvents() inside a loop and managed to return integer value from a function.
The answer to your question "why I need to build up a WebBrowser and return its height from a function" is follow:
I needed to adjust height of iframe at given width in such way, that iframe fits to its content.

Comment: @Zagavarr, `DoEvents` is a bad bandaid for this. This answer is a better route.

Comment: @Rowbear, the `DoSomething` method should be a `Sub` since it does not, or is not required to, return anything.

Comment: @OneFineDay, thanks! I haven't written anything really in vb for nearly a decade and was kind of throwing paint at the canvas. Fixed :)

Comment: @Rowbear, No worries =)